# How to monitor partition mount events with Linux Audit?

Tags: linux

Using Linux Audit, how can I watch for a partition (e.g. /dev/sda5) being mounted? I need to log who did the mount at what time. I've seen examples for watching files and directories, but not for partition mounts.

Comment: Try this; https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-audit/2012-July/msg00008.html. (Sorry, don't have time to test it and post as answer. Feel free to self-answer with it if it works.)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the content of

`/var/log/dmesg`

Comment: I'm trying to avoid rolling my own script/code. Is there a way to configure auditd to watch this file for changes to my partition?

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html